# python - symlink to another symlink without following the latter symlink

Tags: python, macos, symlink, python-3.10

I want to create a symbolic link (A) to another symbolic link (B) which point to an actual file (C) on macOS with python >= 3.10:

A -> B -> C

I tried this:

```py
from pathlib import Path

A = Path('/path/to/src')
B = '/path/to/another/symlink'

A.symlink_to(B)

print(A.resolve()) # prints C, not B
```

But it didn't work.

How do I do this with python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`A.readlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.readlink) instead of `A.resolve()`.